# Deployed of app successful but cannot start

Tags: java, csrf, spring-jdbc, tomcat8, tomcat-manager

I am currently using java 1.8 tomcat8 in debian jessie. I can deploy my app thru tomcat manager but failed to restart. i had this error on logs.

```
20-Feb-2016 16:16:15.063 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
20-Feb-2016 16:16:15.064 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/ch-conso] startup failed due to previous errors
20-Feb-2016 16:16:15.069 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ch-conso] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

[image]

i also get this error on console:

```
20-Feb-2016 09:14:58.226 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
20-Feb-2016 09:14:58.538 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Feb-2016 09:14:58.571 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Feb-2016 09:14:58.576 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Feb-2016 09:14:58.579 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Feb-2016 09:14:58.583 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1137 ms
20-Feb-2016 09:14:58.627 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
20-Feb-2016 09:14:58.627 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
20-Feb-2016 09:14:58.673 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ch-conso.war
20-Feb-2016 09:15:01.501 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

can someone help me understand those errors? i am not into java, im just the one who deployed it.

```
 20-Feb-2016 16:59:06.445 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/manager has finished in 51 ms
20-Feb-2016 16:59:06.446 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/docs
20-Feb-2016 16:59:06.475 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/docs has finished in 29 ms
20-Feb-2016 16:59:06.475 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/host-manager
20-Feb-2016 16:59:06.510 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/host-manager has finished in 35 ms
20-Feb-2016 16:59:06.511 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT
20-Feb-2016 16:59:06.531 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT has finished in 20 ms
20-Feb-2016 16:59:06.546 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Feb-2016 16:59:06.554 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Feb-2016 16:59:06.569 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 12151 ms
20-Feb-2016 17:32:02.646 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ch-conso.war
2016-02-20 17:32:04.656  INFO 443 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Background tasks initialized.
20-Feb-2016 17:32:06.025 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
20-Feb-2016 17:32:06.026 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/ch-conso] startup failed due to previous errors
20-Feb-2016 17:32:06.038 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ch-conso] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
20-Feb-2016 17:32:06.048 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/share/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ch-conso.war has finished in 3,401 ms
2016-02-20 17:32:38.307  INFO 443 --- [io-8080-exec-10] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Background tasks initialized.
20-Feb-2016 17:32:39.327 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
20-Feb-2016 17:32:39.329 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/ch-conso] startup failed due to previous errors
20-Feb-2016 17:32:39.337 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ch-conso] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

Comment: "Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file" ... Can you post relevant part of this log ?

Comment: i edited my post, above was the output when i tailed catalina.out